# Override the specific dictionary, and leave the non-found keys

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I've a `Dictionary<string, string> specDic` that have the resource strings `<Key,Value>`, when I change the language of the app, it got new `Dictionary<string, string> newDic` that have the strings of the new language, but sometimes in the `newDic` we don't have keys that already in the specDic, in other words doesn't translated, I need to override the `specDic` with the `newDic` without override the non-found keys, I tried the following:

```
    foreach (var item in newDic)
    {
        specDic[item.Key] = item.Value;
    }
```

But, I don't loved what I did, does someone can suggest me a new way using linq or somthing?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason for not using [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your logic around, and look for each key from your original dictionary instead:

```
foreach (var key in specDic.Keys)
{
    if (newDic.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        specDic[key] = newDic[key];
    }
}
```

Now, if `newDic` contains a key matching one in `specDic`, the corresponding value in `specDic` will be overridden (or replaced, rather) by the value from `newDic`.

Values (keys) in `specDic` for which there is no corresponding value in `newDic` will remain as they are.